# How to select a postgreSQL row that contains a specific word

Tags: javascript, sql, database, postgresql, knex.js

Trying to build a query for a postgreSQl DB based on a keyword.  LIKE doesn't work as it matches any row that contains any of the letters.  For Example:

SELECT * FROM table WHERE column ilike '%jeep%';

This returns any row that a j,e or p in the column (and the same row multiple times for some reason).  Not the word 'jeep'.

Below is my query structure.  Using Knex and queuing multiple tables:

```
searchAllBoardPosts(db, term) {
        return db
            .select('*')
            .from({
                a: 'messageboard_posts',
                b: 'rentals',
                c: 'market_place',
                d: 'jobs'
            })
            .where('a.title', 'ilike', `%${term}%`)
            .orWhere('b.title', 'ilike', `%${term}%`)
            .orWhere('c.title', 'ilike', `%${term}%`)
            .orWhere('d.title', 'ilike', `%${term}%`);
    },
```

Thanks in advance!

UPDATE:
Here is the SQL output:

```
select * 
from "messageboard_posts" as "a", 
"rentals" as "b",
"market_place" as "c", 
"jobs" as "d" 
where "a"."title" ilike '%jeep%'
or "b"."title" ilike '%jeep%' 
or "c"."title" ilike '%jeep%' 
or "d"."title" ilike '%jeep%'
```

Comment: I assume `.from({ all of those })` is an implicit join, not a union like you want it to be – i.e. the `ILIKE`s are working correctly and you’re finding a pattern that isn’t there in the duplicated results. Can’t find where it’s documented, though. Try logging the SQL it creates?

Comment: So you’re saying `SELECT * FROM table WHERE column ilike ‘jeep’` will match a row where column = “elephant” (since there is an “e” in the string)? I find that hard to believe—can you either update your question with some query output, or re-word your statement in the paragraph after the `SELECT` query example you provided?

Comment: @Ry- from my understanding of Knex (new to it) this structure is a for of aliasing tables to columns when querying multiple tables in one go.  And I do log out the SQL results and it returns 800+ objects but there are only 25 objects in total across all the tables.  The results render in my client as they should but there are hundreds of the same posts.

Comment: @richyen yes I know!  It is hard to believe but that is what I am assuming is the conclusion.  Every row it returns contains at least one leet from the keyword in the desired column.    I will try and add more info to the paragraph.

Comment: Not the SQL results, the SQL. The query it creates. If it looks like `FROM messageboard_posts a, rentals b, market_place c, jobs d`, you’re doing an implicit join. https://github.com/knex/knex/issues/2378

Comment: @Ry- sorry.   Updated the post with the SQL output.  Looks like aliasing to me

Comment: @RyanCarville Yes, you cannot do a `SELECT *` with a union. What results do you actually want from all these tables?

Comment: I just tried a chained union method and got: 
```error: each UNION query must have the same number of columns```
The four tables have different sizes.  I tried to just select the title column form all the tables and this works! But I need to return all the columns from each table that is true.  Maybe select the post id then and additional query to return the corresponding post?

Comment: Not sure it that would work as i noticed when it returns the match it names the keys as the first tables keys and not the table it comes from keys so I can't identify which table it found it in. i.e:
maessageboard_posts has board_id and market_place has market_place_cat but if found in market_place it returns the key as board_id

Comment: You need to select a compatible set of columns from each table before unioning them. If you can’t do that (well, you can, but if it would be too awkward – lots of null padding), just make four separate queries. edit: Oh, this is PostgreSQL? I thought it was SQLite for some reason. You can [convert rows to JSON](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/devel/functions-json.html), then.

Comment: @Ry- that's what o have ended up doing for the moment. Chained four queries them if there are any results from a table I added them to a object and returned the object to the client.  Probably the better way to approach this in the end seeing as they all have different columns and render to different layouts in the client.  But thank you for you help man.  Truly appreciate it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### This query is a cross join

(But the Knex syntax masks that, a little).

> This returns any row that a j,e or p in the column (and the same row multiple times for some reason).

It's not returning the same row multiple times. It's returning everything from each table named in a `CROSS JOIN`. This is the behaviour of Postgres when more than one table is named in the `FROM` clause (see: [docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/sql-select.html#SQL-FROM)). This:

```
db
  .select('*')
  .from({
    a: 'table_one',
    b: 'table_two'
  })
```

will return the *entire row* from *each* of the named tables every time you get an `ILIKE` match. So at minimum you'll always get an object consisting of two rows joined (or however many you name in the `FROM` clause).

The tricky part is, Knex column names have to map to JavaScript objects. This means that if there are two column results named, say, `id` or `title`, the last one will overwrite the first one in the resulting object.

### Let's illustrate (with wombats)

Here's a migration and seed, just to make it clearer:

#### table_one

```
exports.up = knex =>
  knex.schema.createTable("table_one", t => {
    t.increments("id");
    t.string("title");
  });

exports.down = knex => knex.schema.dropTable("table_one");
```

#### table_two

```
exports.up = knex =>
  knex.schema.createTable("table_two", t => {
    t.increments("id");
    t.string("title");
  });

exports.down = knex => knex.schema.dropTable("table_two");
```

#### Seed

```
exports.seed = knex =>
    knex("table_one")
      .del()
      .then(() => knex("table_two").del())
      .then(() =>
        knex("table_one").insert([
          { title: "WILLMATCHwombatblahblahblah" },
          { title: "WILLMATCHWOMBAT" }
        ])
      )
      .then(() =>
        knex("table_two").insert([
          { title: "NEVERMATCHwwwwwww" },
          { title: "wombatWILLMATCH" }
        ])
      )
  );
```

#### Query

This allows us to play around a bit with `ILIKE` matching. Now we need to make the column names really explicit:

```
  return db
    .select([
      "a.id as a.id",
      "a.title as a.title",
      "b.id as b.id",
      "b.title as b.title"
    ])
    .from({
      a: "table_one",
      b: "table_two"
    })
    .where("a.title", "ilike", `%${term}%`)
    .orWhere("b.title", "ilike", `%${term}%`);
```

This produces:

```
[
  {
    'a.id': 1,
    'a.title': 'WILLMATCHwombatblahblahblah',
    'b.id': 1,
    'b.title': 'NEVERMATCHwwwwwww'
  },
  {
    'a.id': 1,
    'a.title': 'WILLMATCHwombatblahblahblah',
    'b.id': 2,
    'b.title': 'wombatWILLMATCH'
  },
  {
    'a.id': 2,
    'a.title': 'WILLMATCHWOMBAT',
    'b.id': 1,
    'b.title': 'NEVERMATCHwwwwwww'
  },
  {
    'a.id': 2,
    'a.title': 'WILLMATCHWOMBAT',
    'b.id': 2,
    'b.title': 'wombatWILLMATCH'
  }
]
```

As you can see, it's cross-joining both tables, but I suspect you were only seeing results that *appeared* not to match (because the match was in the other table, and the `title` column name was a duplicate).

### So, what should the query be?

I think your (or Ry's) plan to use `UNION` was correct, but it's probably worth using `UNION ALL` to avoid unnecessary removal of duplicates. Something like this:

```
  return db
    .unionAll([
      db("market_place")
        .select(db.raw("*, 'marketplace' as type"))
        .where("title", "ilike", `%${term}%`),
      db("messageboard_posts")
        .select(db.raw("*, 'post' as type"))
        .where("title", "ilike", `%${term}%`),
      db("rentals")
        .select(db.raw("*, 'rental' as type"))
        .where("title", "ilike", `%${term}%`),
      db("jobs")
        .select(db.raw("*, 'job' as type"))
        .where("title", "ilike", `%${term}%`)
    ]);
```

A similar query against our test data produces the result set:

```
[
  { id: 1, title: 'WILLMATCHwombatblahblahblah', type: 'table_one' },
  { id: 2, title: 'WILLMATCHWOMBAT', type: 'table_one' },
  { id: 2, title: 'wombatWILLMATCH', type: 'table_two' }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `.union` works and returns the correct values, however using the key tag from the first table in the query. Have ended up just making four separate queries in the end but hope this can help some else!

```
searchAllBoardPosts(db, term) {
        return db
            .union([db
                    .select('id', 'market_place_cat')
                    .from('market_place')
                    .where('title', 'ilike', `%${term}%`)
            ])
            .union([db
                    .select('id', 'board_id')
                    .from('messageboard_posts')
                    .where('title', 'ilike', `%${term}%`)
            ])
            .union([db
                    .select('id', 'rental_cat')
                    .from('rentals')
                    .where('title', 'ilike', `%${term}%`)
            ])
            .union([db
                    .select('id', 'job_cat')
                    .from('jobs')
                    .where('title', 'ilike', `%${term}%`)
            ]);
    },
```

Answer (score -1):

This expression:

```
 WHERE column ilike 'jeep'
```

Only matches rows where the value is `lower(column) = 'jeep'`, such as:

- JEEP
- jeep
- JeeP

It does not match any other expression.

If you use wildcards:

```
 WHERE column ilike '%jeep%'
```

then is looks for `'jeep'` anywhere in `lower(column)`.  It is *not* searching character by character.  For that, you would use regular expressions and character classes:

```
WHERE column ~* '[jep]'
```

If you want to find a *word* in the field, you would normally use regular expressions, not `like`/`ilike`.

Comment: That is what I thought but it doesn't seem to be the case with this one.  I have used ilike  in other queries when targeting one table and it seems to work ok.  But when targeting multiple tables not so much.

Comment: @RyanCarville . . . It is not behaving like a regular expression matcher, unless something in knex or an intermediate layer is changing your code.

Comment: @RyanCarville . . . as for your query, you need `JOIN` conditions among the tables.